# Result complement plus 过

Tags: word-order

I know that both of these follow the verb, but which order do they go in?

Do you say 你看过完那部小说没有 or 你看完过那部小说没有？

Comment: The latter. The former one is just wrong grammatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is grammatically incorrect(not idiomatic). It sounds like no-Chinese speaker trying to speak Chinese. 你看完过 means you finished reading the novel before.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, it is either:

你[看过]那部小说没有? = [Had] you [read] that novel?

or

你[看完]那部小说没有? = [Have] you [finished] reading that novel?

- 看(verb) + 过(verb particle) *marking 'experiential' aspect* = "had read"
- 看(verb) + 完(result complement) *marking 'complete or finish' aspect* = "finish reading"

> in "你看过完那部小说没有?" (had you read finish that novel?), '看过'(had read) already indicated you finished reading the book in the past, '完' is redundant here.

~

> in "你看完过那部小说没有？" (had you ever finish reading the novel?) '看完'(finish reading) already indicated you had finish reading it,  '过' is also redundant 
>   here. This implies  'you had tried to read that novel before, but had never been successful in finish it.'

This question only make sense if someone pick up a novel and only read half of it, then few weeks later pick it up again, read it from the start and stop at the middle again. Kind of weird, right?

~

A more sensible examples of [V] +[result complement]+ [过 (verb particle)]:

看见过 (had seen)

- 看(verb- **to see**)
- 见 (result complement- **and successfully seen**)
- 过 (verb particle) - *marking 'experiential' aspect- **had experienced***

**conclusion:**

[Verb + 过] cannot be followed by '完'(redundant)

[Verb + 完 + 过] indicate "had finished (verb) before"

Comment: Good job covering the grammar question _and_ pointing out that it's not a great example _and_ coming up with a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaim: the following are totally my personal idea. Maybe I am incorrect, but I think these are valid.

Neither of them is right to my ear. I would say

> 你（以前）看过那部小说没有？//// Have you read that novel?

and

> 你看完那部小说没有？////
>   Have you finished that novel?

过 just mean you did something, while 完 indicates that you finished that thing. Fortunately your 2nd choice could be understood by natives, which is equivalent to my 2nd sentence, i.e. the 过 is automatically omitted when people listen to you.